# Can I combine the exotics for a payout?

Tags: option-pricing, probability, exotics

Can I combine a **one touch option**(barrier lower than current price) and **no touch option**(barrier higher than current price), so that I get a payout immediately **only if** the one touch barrier is breached **first** before the no touch **“May be”** breached later?

Can a bank, market maker, issuer e.t.c price such a combination of exotics as one single product?

Comment: Simply adding the two together will not give you the price of one derivative conditional on another. These two products can be used to hedge some of the risks of the combined derivative, and in some scenarios the values may be very very close (but that could change as prices move around)

Comment: So can a bank price it as one derivative? Is it a complex process? @will

Comment: Yes, no problem to price them. Not just banks, many vendors can do that too. Think of Monte Carlo runs (with whatever model is available), you know at every iteration what the value of the underlying is.

Comment: You wrote vendors: did you mean like issuers or brokers et cetera? Also is access to trading such a customized single derivative available for retail or just only for the H.N.W.I and professional traders? @AKdemy

Comment: This [link](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/product/bloomberg-data-management-services/) has a list of some vendors. Bloomberg DLIB (derivatives library) for example. If you can trade it will depend on your legislation. [This](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/65763/54838) and [that](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/65683/54838) may be interesting. If you don't know if it's available or how it can be priced, it's best to not touch it.

Comment: Okay, would checkout the links, thank you.